# Arch installation crashes on grub-install

Tags: linux, boot, motherboard, grub, arch-linux

In an `arch-chroot` environment on an Arch live USB, I'm trying to install GRUB (for a new install of Arch Linux).

```
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot
```

But the output is:

```
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
```

and then it crashes (the cursor blinks a few times, and then stops blinking, and the computer becomes unresponsive until I force shut it off with the power button).

I was able to install it successfully and without issues on a similar set of hardware before (as well as many other computers), so that is why I'm confused. (The "similar set of hardware" is because the motherboard was defective with some RAM slots broken, so I ordered a new one from a different seller.) Because the only difference is the motherboard, I updated BIOS and other firmware from it to the latest version, but that didn't fix the problem.

I found [this thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2400667) which suggests that it might have something to do with Secure Boot, but my motherboard doesn't seem to have that option in its BIOS (for reference: it's the [S5520UR](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/support/us/en/documents/motherboards/server/s5520ur/sb/e44031012_s5520ur_s5520urt_tps_r1_9.pdf)); again, I don't think this is the problem because it worked on the other motherboard.

Are there any likely problems causing this, knowing that it is possible (i.e., the hardware should support UEFI boot)?

**Edit** Just ran it with `--debug` and it seems to hang on this statement:

```
efibootmgr -c -d /dev/sda -p 1 -w -L arch -l \EFI\arch\grubx64.efi
```

**Edit 2** After finding the line that crashes it, found someone with the [same issue](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=730639) (but unresolved) with a S5520SC board (nearly the same model as mine).

Here's [another issue](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/crash-during-grub-reinstallation-executing-efibootmgr/79053/10) that suggests that the newest version of `efibootmgr` (which was upgraded fairly recently) might be the cause. Will try it out.

Comment: Didn't you forget the `--bootloader-id` option in grub install command? And the EFI directory should be `/boot/grub`.

Comment: @Biswapriyo `—boot loader-id` seems to be optional (default is `arch`). And the latter depends on where you mount the esp, which is `/boot` for me